Problem in taking second input . And laptop showing a box screen
My laptop taking first input correctly but when i press enter button then it showing a box and not taking second input . And then i press renter button laptop takes similar input as first input so some one can help with this.

There are 1k+ programming languages, pick one and we can help you better, some code also might help

Write details about where  you are entering your input and where is screen popping out

not an answer but a comment
